# Extracting Max value along each row from strings in column

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I've a column of strings in a DataFrame which contains comma-separated numbers. I need to extract the maximum value along each row from the strings. The maximum value returned should be the max till the 13th index from the beginning.

I've tried splitting the sting using ',' as a separator to convert it into a list with expand option enabled. Then I'm using the assign method of Pandas to find the max value along the vertical axis.

```py
sample_dt1 = sample_dt['pyt_hist'].str.split(',', expand=True).astype(float)
sample_dt = sample_dt.assign(max_value=sample_dt1.max(axis=1))
```

Sample Data:

```py
index    pyt_hist
0        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
1        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
2        0,0,0,360,420,392,361,330,300,269,239,208,177
3        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,23,0,0,56,0
```

Expected Result:

```py
index    pyt_hist                                           max_value
0        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0                              0
1        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0      0
2        0,0,0,360,420,392,361,330,300,269,239,208,177      420
3        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,23,0,0,56,0       0
```

Results obtained using my code:

```py
index    pyt_hist                                           max_value
0        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0                              0.0
1        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0      0.0
2        0,0,0,360,420,392,361,330,300,269,239,208,177      420.0
3        0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,23,0,23,0,0,56,0       56.0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
df.pyt_hist.str.split(',').apply(lambda x: max([int(i) for i in x[:13] if i]))
```

**Output**

```
0      0
1      0
2    420
3      0
Name: pyt_hist, dtype: int64
```

Comment: I'm getting the following error due to `int(i)`: `ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` If I use `i*1` instead of `int(i)` then for the string `150,150,150,150,150,150,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,90,0,0,60,0,0,0,0,60,60,60,0,0,60,60,60,60,60,60,60` it returns `90` instead of `150`

Comment: is there any empty values in the list, also i am getting 90 for the example with the above list using the same code..

Comment: I can't see any empty values in my list. However, just to avoid this, how can I filter or strip the empty values to make your code work for all cases?

Comment: For some cases it's now throwing an error: `ValueError: max() arg is an empty sequence`

Comment: the list is not empty. it is list of strings and contains 'None' and these are not getting converted into numbers. also, instead of max of first 12 elements, how can I get max of 1st 3 elements from right?

Comment: this seems to be a separate prob, please open a new q for that

Answer (score 2):

You are very close,  `sample_dt1.iloc[:,:13]` gives you the first 13 columns of `sample_dt1`. So you can do:

```
sample_dt = sample_dt.assign(max_value=sample_dt1.iloc[:,:13].max(axis=1))
```